# ServiceStack - How to increase the gateway timeout?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am calling my ServiceStack service to run a long running process.  (ServiceStack 4.011)

I keep getting a Gateway Timeout error after approximately 60 seconds.

I tried to set the timeout to be longer on the client (see below) but it isn't helping.  I still get the gateway timeout error after 60 seconds.

Can anyone help me extend the timeout so that I don't get a Gateway Timeout error?

```
jsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient(ncdServiceAddress);

client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,5,0);  // 5 min
```

The full error is below.

```
NCD.DataPump.Cache_Coverages_Pump.PumpDOT_CarriersToNCD_fromLastUpdatedDate_usingS3' failed: Gateway Timeout
    ServiceStack.WebServiceException: Gateway Timeout
    at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.ThrowWebServiceException[TResponse](Exception ex, String requestUri)
    at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.ThrowResponseTypeException[TResponse](Object request, Exception ex, String requestUri)
    at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.HandleResponseException[TResponse](Exception ex, Object request, String requestUri, Func`1 createWebRequest, Func`2 getResponse, TResponse& response)
    at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Send[TResponse](Object request)
```

Comment: Are you going through a proxy?  Your proxy might well be set to 60 seconds.  If so, try changing your proxy settings to not use a proxy for local connections (assuming this connection is on the local network)

Comment: No proxy.  (That I'm aware of.)

Comment: Bizarre.  I use ServiceStack extensively, and some data is huge and requires a *lot* of processing, and can take upwards of 10 minutes.  The only time I had issues, where every 2 minutes *on the nose*, was when it was trying to go out via proxy.

Comment: Are you going outside of your local network for this call, or is it all internal?

Comment: Going outside the network.

Comment: Gateway Timeouts normally mean that the request is going through an intermediary proxy server which fails with a Gateway error when it doesn't get a response from the downstream server within its specified timeout. As it's likely going through a proxy server you wont be able to specify it within client or server. A solution is to reduce the execution time of the request, either by partitioning it in smaller workloads or running it in the background, return immediately and poll for status updates.

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  I'll see if I can re-engineer to get an instant return and process in the background.